# How would I read an ascii string of hex values in to a byte array?

Tags: vb.net

How would I copy/convert a string containing an ascii representation of hex values in to a byte array containing the actual hex values?  For example, I have a variable containing the hex values delimited by spaces (I can change the delimiter):

myString = "24 01 66 09 13 2F 1E 00 00 4E"

I want to put those values into a byte array:

Dim myByteArr(9) as Byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Shared Function HexToBytes(ByVal s As String) As Byte()
    Dim bytes As String() = s.Split(" "c)
    Dim retval(bytes.Length - 1) As Byte
    For ix As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
        retval(ix) = Byte.Parse(bytes(ix), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
    Next
    Return retval
End Function
```

Comment: You could further shorten this by using Array.ConvertAll, if desired