# How to put chars that actually represent hex values in a byte array

Tags: c#, string, char, hex, arrays

I have a string `text = 0a00...4c617374736e6e41`. This string actually contains hex values as chars. What I am trying to do is to the following conversion, without changing e. g. the char `a` to `0x41`;

```
text = 0a...4c617374736e6e41;
--> byte[] bytes = {0x0a, ..., 0x4c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x74, 0x73, 0x6e, 0x6e, 0x41};
```

This is what I tried to implement so far:

```
...
string text = "0a00...4c617374736e6e41";
var storage = StringToByteArray(text)
...
Console.ReadKey();

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string text)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[text.Length/2];
    byte[] bytes = new byte[text.length/2];
    using(StringReader sr = new StringReader(text))
    {
        int c = 0;
        while(c <= text.Length)
        {
            sr.Read(buffer, 0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(buffer);
            //How do I store the blocks in the byte array in the needed format?
            c +=2;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine(buffer)` gives me the two chars I need. But I have NO idea how to put them in the desired format.

Here are some links I already found in the topic, however I were not able to transfer that to my problem:

- [How would I read an ascii string of hex values in to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296000/how-would-i-read-an-ascii-string-of-hex-values-in-to-a-byte-array)
- [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa/2556329#2556329)

Comment: And that example byte array looks like it is encoded text. Just be sure to know which character set and encoding the sender chose if you are going to decode it. If the sender has not communicated that information to you then you have a broken contract/failed communication/data loss.

Comment: Hey @TomBlodget. Can you give me some further explanation? I still have some issues/problems:

The bytestream represents a certain structure. Elements are:
`MessageId, MessageLanguage, MessageText`.

`Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(ByteArray))` gives me the correct `MessageLanguage = de` and `MessageText = This is sample text`. The console also prints a `?` and a lot of empty spaces.

Do you have any hints?

I think, if we can resolve this, I will adjust and complete my original question.

Comment: You just need to reverse the steps that were used to create the structure in the first place. When it comes to bytes that represent text, you simply use code like in your comment except instead of guessing that the encoding is UTF-16 (`Encoding.Unicode`), you need to use the encoding that you know it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
            string text = "0a004c617374736e6e41";
            List<byte> output = new List<byte>();
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i += 2)
            {
                output.Add(byte.Parse(text.Substring(i,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            }
```

Comment: This actually is very easy. I've been blind. Thank you @jdweng